# AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'lower' for txt file

Tags: python

Here is my code (A pig **Latin translator** from a text file):

```
f = open('Assignment_4.txt', 'r+')

for line in f:
    print(line)

def pigLatin():
    var = 'ay'
    wordL = f.lower()
    firstLetter = wordL[0]
    pigLatin = wordL + firstLetter + var
    pigLatin = pigLatin[1:]
    print(pigLatin)
```

It works for defined strings but won't for the file. Help is appreciated!

Comment: did you mean `line.lower()` rather than `f.lower()`?

Comment: Your code is not a runnable example. Nothing calls `pigLatin`!

Answer (score 0):

**Points:**

- `lower()` works with string. You are trying to use with file handle `f`. That's why you are getting this error.
- Also, after reading file line by line, you should call `pigLatin()` for each line as `pigLatin(line)`. So, now , pigLatin() function expects one argument.
- Also, close the file at the end as `f.close()`.  It will be if you use `with` statement to open file.

**Code with comments inline:**

```
def pigLatin(stuff_to_be_changed):
    var = 'ay'
    wordL = stuff_to_be_changed.lower()
    firstLetter = wordL[0]
    pigLatin = wordL + firstLetter + var
    pigLatin = pigLatin[1:]
    print(pigLatin)


#For string

string =  "I am to change"
#Call function
pigLatin(string)

f = open('Assignment_4.txt', 'r+')

#For file
for line in f:
    print(line)
    #Call function
    pigLatin(line)

#Close the file
f.close()
```

Comment: Don't use the same name as the function, inside the function. It just leads to confusion. You are now converting the entire _line_, you need to convert each _word_.

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite right - file objects don't have a `lower()` method - before you can use your function you need to `read` a line of text from your file and `split` it into separate words. (Note that it is never a good idea to use the same name for a variable and a method as it can cause confusion.)